# converting string to char * fails (codecvt)

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code:

```
std::wstring my_string = L"foo";
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> > my_conv;
const char *chars = my_conv.to_bytes( my_string ).c_str();
```

The conversion return an empty pointer (Not `NULL`, just `""`).

Is `to_bytes` returning a temporary pointer?
How do I write this code properly?

Comment: `to_bytes` doesn't return a pointer to char. Please post a [mcve]. I cannot [reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/6af4ej) this.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. 'pronouns' m, I have MSVC 2017 Community, runing on Windows 8.1. What's your environment? And what do you mean `it doesn't return a pointer to char`?

Comment: It returns std::string. Anyway, this entire facility is deprecated.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm., in what standard it is deprecated? And how one suppose to convert `std::wstring` to `char *`? Also - I missed the call to `c_str()`. Added.

Comment: @Igor `std::wstring_convert` is deprecated in C++17 onward

Comment: @RemyLebeau, so how do I reliably convert it?

Comment: @Igor the standard hasn't provided an alternative to replace `std::wstring_convert` yet (if it ever will). `std::wstring_convert` still *works* for now, but it *will* be removed one day in a future standard (maybe in C++23 or C++26, who knows when).  So, if you want to future-proof your code now then just use a 3rd party Unicode conversion library instead, like ICONV or ICU, or else convert the data manually, as UTF-8 is fairly easy to implement by hand.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, is there a version of `iconv` for MSVC? I googled and it looks like there is none. And what about `ICU`?

Comment: @Igor There are 3rd party ports of ICONV for Windows, such as [LibIconv for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm). ICU has native support for MSVC, and is also [built in to Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/international-components-for-unicode--icu-). Though, on Windows, you can just use Microsoft's [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte) function via the `CP_UTF8` codepage, using `std::wstring` as the input buffer and `std::string` as the output buffer

Comment: @RemyLebeau, well I prefer to use one code for all 3 major platforms - Windows, *nix and OSX. Hence the question. However, for now I will try to keep my code with C++11. Thx for suggestions though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, probably they think to bring an iconv to the standard. Just like they did for STL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::wstring_convert::to_bytes()` does not return a temporary *pointer*.  It returns a temporary `std::string` *object*.  You are saving a pointer to the temporary's data, and then the temporary goes out of scope and gets destroyed afterwards, leaving you with a **dangling pointer** to invalid memory.

Save the `std::string` itself, not a `char*` pointer to its data, eg:

```cpp
std::wstring my_string = L"foo";
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> > my_conv;
std::string chars = my_conv.to_bytes( my_string );
// now use chars.c_str() when needed...
```